# Pandas pivot manipulation replace None with last row value

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a dataframe with idex as datetime, different ids and different values
I have a df as :

```
data = [
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-15 14:31:20.507", "id" : "usr_21",  "value": "-1.286452"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-16 15:17:45.550", "id" : "usr_15",  "value": "-2.349203"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-17 14:20:47.437", "id" : "usr_13",  "value": "-2.397038"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-19 09:43:47.262", "id" : "usr_12",  "value": "-1.250512"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-19 15:18:47.941", "id" : "usr_21",  "value": "-0.681998"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-19 20:03:52.905", "id" : "usr_15",   "value": "-1.018452"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-22 13:40:48.178", "id" : "usr_21",  "value": "-1.531373"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-22 19:54:48.320", "id" : "usr_18",  "value": "-3.789466"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-23 13:53:48.789", "id" : "usr_21",  "value": "-1.288360"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-24 15:54:48.649", "id" : "usr_21",  "value": "0.213171"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-25 17:53:48.422", "id" : "usr_13",  "value": "-2.020710"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-26 06:10:48.197", "id" : "usr_12",  "value": "-1.484709"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-15 14:31:20.507", "id" : "usr_21",  "value": "-1.286452"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-16 15:18:45.550", "id" : "usr_18",  "value": "-2.349203"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-17 14:18:47.437", "id" : "usr_11",  "value": "-2.397038"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-19 09:48:47.262", "id" : "usr_15",  "value": "-1.250512"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-19 15:18:47.941", "id" : "usr_21",  "value": "-0.681998"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-19 20:03:52.905", "id" : "usr_13",  "value": "-1.018452"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-22 13:53:48.178", "id" : "usr_21",  "value": "-1.531373"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-22 19:53:48.320", "id" : "usr_18",  "value": "-3.789466"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-23 13:53:48.789", "id" : "usr_21",  "value": "-1.288360"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-24 15:53:48.649", "id" : "usr_11",  "value": "0.213171"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-25 16:53:48.422", "id" : "usr_13",  "value": "-2.020710"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-26 06:08:48.197", "id" : "usr_15",  "value": "-1.484709"}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['datetime_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_start'])
```

I want a representation of this data as a pivot

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index='id'],
                     columns=['index'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

[image: im1]
so for each (id, datetime) we have a value 
if there is no value it's a None

Is there an elegant way to replace the None value with this rules:

```
if value(id_i, datetime_i) == None :
    if value(id_i, datetime_i-1)  != 0 :
        value(id_i, datetime_i) = value(id_i, datetime_i-1)
    else:
        value(id_i, datetime_i) = 0
```

as this kind of propagation :

[image]

Comment: Sorry, so finally first row is `0,0,None, -2.397038,-2.397038, None, None,...` ? Or there are finally no NaNs?

Comment: yes we need to propagation the 0, and also values .
no None anymore :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need change `columns=['index']` to `columns='datetime_start'` first and then use `ffill` ([`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with `method='ffill'`):

```
table = (pd.pivot_table(df, 
                        values='value', 
                        index='id', 
                        columns='datetime_start', 
                        aggfunc=np.sum)
           .ffill(axis=1, limit=1))
```

EDIT with less data:

```
data = [
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-15 14:31:20.507", "id" : "usr_21",  "value": "-1.286452"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-16 15:17:45.550", "id" : "usr_15",  "value": "-2.349203"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-17 14:20:47.437", "id" : "usr_13",  "value": "-2.397038"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-19 09:43:47.262", "id" : "usr_12",  "value": "-1.250512"},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['datetime_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_start'])

table = (pd.pivot_table(df, 
                        values='value', 
                        index='id', 
                        columns='datetime_start', 
                        aggfunc=np.sum)
         )


print (table)
datetime_start 2017-03-15 14:31:20.507 2017-03-16 15:17:45.550  \
id                                                               
usr_12                            None                    None   
usr_13                            None                    None   
usr_15                            None               -2.349203   
usr_21                       -1.286452                    None   

datetime_start 2017-03-17 14:20:47.437 2017-03-19 09:43:47.262  
id                                                              
usr_12                            None               -1.250512  
usr_13                       -2.397038                    None  
usr_15                            None                    None  
usr_21                            None                    None
```

Replace only one value `None` if previous value is not `None` - then add parameter `limit`:

```
table1 = (pd.pivot_table(df, 
                        values='value', 
                        index='id', 
                        columns='datetime_start', 
                        aggfunc=np.sum)
           .ffill(axis=1, limit=1)
           )

print (table1)
datetime_start 2017-03-15 14:31:20.507 2017-03-16 15:17:45.550  \
id                                                               
usr_12                            None                    None   
usr_13                            None                    None   
usr_15                            None               -2.349203   
usr_21                       -1.286452               -1.286452   

datetime_start 2017-03-17 14:20:47.437 2017-03-19 09:43:47.262  
id                                                              
usr_12                            None               -1.250512  
usr_13                       -2.397038               -2.397038  
usr_15                       -2.349203                    None  
usr_21                            None                    None
```

Replace all `NaN`s by previous non `NaNs`, last replace all `NaN`s by `0`, remove `limit` and add `fillna(0)`:

```
table2 = (pd.pivot_table(df, 
                        values='value', 
                        index='id', 
                        columns='datetime_start', 
                        aggfunc=np.sum)
            .ffill(axis=1)
            .fillna(0)
           )

print (table2)
datetime_start 2017-03-15 14:31:20.507 2017-03-16 15:17:45.550  \
id                                                               
usr_12                               0                       0   
usr_13                               0                       0   
usr_15                               0               -2.349203   
usr_21                       -1.286452               -1.286452   

datetime_start 2017-03-17 14:20:47.437 2017-03-19 09:43:47.262  
id                                                              
usr_12                               0               -1.250512  
usr_13                       -2.397038               -2.397038  
usr_15                       -2.349203               -2.349203  
usr_21                       -1.286452               -1.286452
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, as usual your tricks are awsome. Are you a Pandas wizard ^^ ?
That's great, but just watch for table21.iloc[-1] and  table2.iloc[-1] (when importing the totaly df)
Values are in double ....

Comment: Hmmm, I am not sure if understand you. What is desired ouptut with `data = [
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-15 14:31:20.507", "id" : "usr_21",  "value": "-1.286452"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-16 15:17:45.550", "id" : "usr_15",  "value": "-2.349203"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-17 14:20:47.437", "id" : "usr_13",  "value": "-2.397038"},
{ 'datetime_start' : "2017-03-19 09:43:47.262", "id" : "usr_12",  "value": "-1.250512"},
]` ? Can you add to answer? Or need only `.ffill(axis=1, limit=1)
            .fillna(0)` ? Thanks.

Comment: that's ok you're totaly right I will change my df data to be in a perfect way 
I mad replication data